# How do I seal seams between bricks on a patio without using sand?

Tags: brick, grout, patio

I have a patio that's made of bricks with fine sand filling the gaps. This is turning out to be a maintenance hassle. Every time the kid or dog gets mud or crud on the patio I hose it off and manage to blow more and more sand out of the cracks.

Is there a way to seal the seams between the bricks or use something more sticky than sand... like a fine grout? I like the look just fine, but it appears that I'm going to be spending a lot more time than I desire on maintenance of my patio.

Answer (score 7):

What you are looking for is a [joint sand stabilizing sealer](http://www.pavetech.com/paveChem/sand.shtml).  That should prevent washout as well as weed growth in the joints.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I had not seen this product before.

Comment: @JD - Not specifically recommending that product or anything, just found it on a google search.  I'm sure there are lots of other alternative products as well.

Comment: I like the sound of this, esp. since they claim it's "rubberized" and will allow some thermal expansion of your pavers.  My main concern with ChrisF's answer was that the mortar might crack after a while and not look so great.

Answer (score 5):

You could mix up a fine sand & cement mixture brush that into the gaps then water the patio to turn that into mortar in place.

You'd need to make sure the patio was clean first, and don't use too much water.

Though this would be a fairly permanent solution.

Comment: I was considering exactly this... wanted to get other input before I made a big mess ;)

Comment: @JD Long - It might be worth testing it out on a small area first.

Comment: That's always a good idea! My wife thanks you for reminding me. ;)

Comment: This works very well in my experience and is standard practice in my area.  The key is to make it a very lean mix - put 1/2 or even 1/4 as much cement as the directions call for: it should be mostly sand.  You don't *want* strength, just for it to harden somewhat.  Brush it in when it's dry outside then lightly sprinkle it with water.

Answer (score 1):

Fill them with sand then carefully add pure cement to the top of the crack and lightly spray with a mist until the cement washes down into the sand and then no more. Let it set a day.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the polymeric sand.  It is sand mixed with some binding agent.  You fill the gaps with this sand.  Use a broom to remove excess from the brick surface.  Sprinkle some water at the joints and the chemical reaction starts.  My experience with a specific product was so so.  May be I did not do it right.  But polymeric sand claims to be for the purpose, you are looking.

[Here is the link to buy from Lowes.](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Sakrete-40-lb-Gray-Polymeric-Sand/4752128)